# How to start and stop a timer in Java

Tags: java, timer

I am not very good at Java...

I am working on a stopwatch, with a start, stop and reset button.

When u press start, it obviously starts. When u press stop, it pauses( using `timer.cancel();`). When u press reset it makes all the values 0, and stops. and when u press start again, it should continue to count, where it was stopped(unless it was reset).

I am using a `java.util.timer;`
So here  is the question:
How do you start a timer, that was paused(canceled)? For example, if I used the stop button to stop it. And in my code it would look like this: `timer.cancel();`, how can I start it again??

I know that you can do this using `timer.stop()` and `timer.start()` in `vb`

```
 import java.util.Timer;
 import java.util.TimerTask;

public static void timerStart()
{

        //timer
        if(running == false)
        {

            TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
            { 


                public void run()
                {
                    //what to do at each excecution
                    seconds++;
                    lbl.setText(Short.toString(seconds));
                }
            };

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,1000,1000);
        }
        running = true;
}
```

and

```
 public static void timerStop()
 {
    timer.cancel();
    runnig = false;
 }
```

Comment: @JoxTraex: how do you know that this is a java.util.Timer? For all we know the OP could be talking about a javax.swing.Timer. Original poster, you will want to improve this question so that we know unambiguously what you're asking about. Also please show us your code attempts and let us know how they're not working, preferably as a [mcve].

Comment: You're right, i thought i saw an android tag here. My mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am using a java.util.timer;

Well you should  be using a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a couple of reasons:

1. It has stop() and restart() methods.
2. Swing components should be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: thanks, I will try that!

Comment: that solved my problem!!!